# Ng select ng template duplicate values

Tags: angular, typescript

Ng select shows the duplicate values if we selct mutiple vales.

```
 <ng-select [(ngModel)]="selectedValues" [items]="options" bindLabel="label" bindValue="value" [multiple]="true" [clearable]="false">
      <ng-template ng-label-tmp let-item="item" let-clear="clear">
        <!-- Show each selected value on a separate row -->
        <div *ngFor="let selectedValue of selectedValues">
          {{ selectedValue }}
        </div>
      </ng-template>
    </ng-select>
```